# for loop + List in Lists leading to same value for all indices

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, reddit, praw

what i wanted was each list inside list is the top 10 answers to that specific url (y[i]). However it appears it is replacing all the lists in the list with only the last url's comments. here is what i tried (ALT 2 as well which didn't work..)

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='L685-1uBBrLbKQ', client_secret='_Fk5nW1L2h3VRR6BVnkusMh43QQ_gg', user_agent='Shivam Anand')
    
hot_posts = reddit.subreddit('AskReddit').top(time_filter="day", limit=5)
x=[]
y=[]

for post in hot_posts:
    x.append(post.title)
    y.append(post.url)
    print(x)
    print(y)

z = [[""] * 10] * len(x)
for i,j in enumerate(y):
    print(i)
    print(j)
    submission = reddit.submission(url=j)
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0)
    for commentcount in range(0, 10):
        print(commentcount)
        z[i][commentcount] = submission.comments[commentcount].body
    del submission 

#ALT 2


# z=[[]]*len(x)
# for i,j in enumerate(y):
#     print(i)
#     print(j)
#     try:
#         del submission
#     except:
#         print("na")
#     submission = reddit.submission(url=j)
#     submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0)
#     for commentcount in range(0, 10):
#         print(commentcount)
#         print(j)
#         z[i].append(submission.comments[commentcount].body)
```

Here is the fraudulent list generated [Fraud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foCpw.png)

Comment: I think you have a bug elsewhere, because your list of list `z` should indeed be getting the `commentcount` value, just test your loop without the `submission` object to convince  yourself

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict instead:

```py
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='L685-1uBBrLbKQ', client_secret='_Fk5nW1L2h3VRR6BVnkusMh43QQ_gg', user_agent='Shivam Anand')
    
hot_posts = reddit.subreddit('AskReddit').top(time_filter="day", limit=5)
x=[]
y=[]

for post in hot_posts:
    x.append(post.title)
    y.append(post.url)
    print(x)
    print(y)

z = {} #dictionary
for i,j in enumerate(y):
    print(i)
    print(j)
    z[i] = {} #nested dictionary
    submission = reddit.submission(url=j)
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0)
    for commentcount in range(0, 10):
        print(commentcount)
        z[i][commentcount] = submission.comments[commentcount].body
    del submission
```

Test:

```py
for i, k in enumerate(z, start=1):
    print(f"Post {i}")
    for j, l in enumerate(z[k], start=1):        
        print(f"Comment {j}: {z[k][l][:30]}")
```

Output:

```
Post 1
Comment 1: My grandmother was brilliant a
Comment 2: I worked in a care facility fo
Comment 3: My sister passed away earlier
Comment 4: A long-time friend of mine sta
Comment 5: I was living elsewhere at the
Comment 6: It was not really all that slo
Comment 7: I have type I bipolar disorder
Comment 8: Watched my grandfather slowly
Comment 9: I was in high school and my be
Comment 10: I watched my ex wife slowly sp
Post 2
Comment 1: I found my dad's body after he
Comment 2: My grandad was a few months sh
Comment 3: A full family (father mother +
Comment 4: In November of 2004- I had a v
Comment 5: Found my dad dead (heart attac
Comment 6: My friend from school crashed
Comment 7: Went to check on my uncle beca
Comment 8: I was at the shooting range on
Comment 9: I used to work at this sports
Comment 10: One night I was out walking my
Post 3
Comment 1: On December 21, 2020 Jupiter a
Comment 2: The average color of the unive
Comment 3: No one who was born blind has
Comment 4: The origin of the word "happin
Comment 5: Rodents can't vomit.
Comment 6: Squirrels can acquire terminal
Comment 7: Wombats and some other Austral
Comment 8: The shower water on Alcatraz w
Comment 9: That vets can "transplant" fea
Comment 10: The Native Americans of the Gr
Post 4
Comment 1: The **clear craze** in the lat
Comment 2: Jacks...I'm older than dirt.
Comment 3: Silly bands
Comment 4: Furbies, absolutely needed to
Comment 5: Crackle nail polish. Why did w
Comment 6: Cell phones that worked like w
Comment 7: Idk if this is just where I li
Comment 8: Cup stacking...what was that a
Comment 9: Hypercolor clothing
Comment 10: No one ever talks about little
Post 5
Comment 1: **Attention! [Serious] Tag Not
Comment 2: I want to run a food truck nea
Comment 3: Lego designer and model tester
Comment 4: I would love to make a living
Comment 5: Carpenter.
Comment 6: Park ranger living in an off t
Comment 7: A geology professor! With a pa
Comment 8: Environmental consultant or a
Comment 9: Ever since I was a kid I wante
Comment 10: Shepherd.
```